# Compress and copy same time to another server - slow

Tags: ftp, 7zip

i have a big problem. I need tranfer a lot of files by a server to another server, but the second server isnt a local server. If i tranfer by a local server i cant 100mbs but if i send for another server out the speed is 2mbs. my network is 1gbs. I use a command line 7z.

Comment: And what is your exact problem ? As you won't be able to increase the 2mbps line you will need to make best use of it. So using the highest compression on 7zip (and the 7z file format, not .zip) will perhaps help the most. It might help if you show us a picture how your servers are connected and what is the up- and downstream of your networks connecting them.

Comment: My problem is simple to see. I have three servers, one origin and two destiny. The uplink is the same, i tranfer using 7z command line and the first i have 60mbs by speed. A second is not me i have 2mbs. But the line is the same.

Comment: I use this command line: c:\scripts\7za.exe a -r -tzip -mmt=4 -mx=1 \\srseguro02\srv.ZIP "C:\ClusterStorage\srv\*.vhd*"

Answer (score 0):

If your servers are (as you wrote) on the same network and connected through the same line you are most likely to have a network connection problem.

I've often seen that the duplex settings of network cards are not set up correctly which leads to a lot of collisions.

Check your network card settings and try to force for example 100mbps full duplex.

I work for a company where this happens daily when trying to connect IBM network cards with Cisco switches. Have a look here how to set up duplex settings: https://superuser.com/questions/86581/how-do-you-check-the-current-duplex-value-of-a-network-card-set-to-auto-negotiat.
If this doesn´t help you might be better off asking at superuser.com